# ViewPager designed to work in Portrait mode recreates fragments on orientation change

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a rather strange issue while working with ViewPager fragments and orientation change.
My problem in the most simplistic description is as follows:

My application has one activity (MainActivity) that is designed to work in both Portrait and Landscape mode. I am using different layouts in different orientations - A ViewPager in portrait and a simple fragment with a completely different view in landscape. Both these components are independent of each other.

The fragment code I am using in both my ViewPager fragments and my landscape fragment are simple - an onAttach(), onDetach() and onCreateView() where I inflate my view are overridden.

I am not really concerned about retaining fragments when I change orientation as I am showing a completely different layout. However, my issue is that the ViewPager fragments are destroyed and recreated (onDestroy() -> onDetach() -> onAttach() -> onCreate() -> onCreateView()) in landscape mode even when not visible.

Is there a workaround to not recreate these fragments on orientation change?

My MainActivity's onCreate() code is as follows and I am checking orientation in onCreate() to decide what view components need to be intialized.

```
private ViewPager mPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.empty);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.empty);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.portraitviewpager);
        if (mPager != null) {
            mPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            mPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DepthPageTransformer());
            mPager.setCurrentItem(HOME);    
        }
    } 

}
```

Also, just to make things more simple, my SectionsPagerAdapter code is as follows:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case MAIN_MENU:
            return MainMenuFragment.newInstance();
        case HOME:
            return HomeFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setRetainInstance(true);` to the `onAttach(Activity activity)` of the `ViewPager` fragments.

---

```
Open for correction, as Always!

Regards,
Edward Quixote.
```

Comment: setRetainInstance(true) would not recreate fragments on orientation change. But I am using different layouts for portrait & landscape & when I go back to portrait mode again after orientation change, I am forced to get a reference to my pager & create the fragments again, which does not help my cause. I could do with either not recreating fragments at all on orientation change after they are created once or creating them when they are required to be shown (If it is landscape fragment recreate only in landscape & vice versa). I do not think setRetainInstance would be useful in that case then.